# twig template sort insensitive case

Tags: twig

I need to sort an array in branch templates but case insensitive, it's similar to '[strnatcasecmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php)' in php. It is an array of objects having id and name, i want to sort by name.

I'm doing:

```
{% for station in value|sort((a, b) => a.name <=> b.name) %}
 <div> ... </div>
{%endfor%}
```

But it is putting the names in lowercase at last the list. I need to sort them case insensitive. It's possible?

Comment: Why not use a proper Twig filter for this? This would also enable your code to be tested

Comment: Change the condition to `|sort((a, b) => a.name|lower <=> b.name|lower)`?